# How do I perform an action on mousedown when a certain element is NOT clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code that I want to execute a command if the click is not on the rl_menu / any of it's child elements (.comment, .rl_arrow, etc)

```
TBR.mouse_down = function(e){
    target = $j(this)
    if (target != $j("#rl_menu") && target != $j("#rl_menu .comment") &&
    target != $j("#rl_menu .change") && target != $j("#rl_menu .rl_arrow_border") &&
    target != $j("#rl_menu .rl_arrow")){
        TBR.Menu.hide(); // this needs to be triggered when the menu is not clicked on.
    }
}
```

but when I inspect target, target is the document.

To recap:

Anywhere in the document, when the mouse is pressed, `TBR.Menu.hide()` should be executed. but if the click is within `#rl_menu`, `TBR.Menu.hide()` shouldn't be executed.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this down a bit easyer?

```
$(function(){

    $("body").click(function(e){
        var t = $(e.target);
        if( !t.is("#rl_menu") && t.closest("#rl_menu").length == 0)
        {
            alert("CLICKD OUTSIDE THE GREEN")
        }
    });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JBuJm/

Answer (score 0):

If you events bubble up the `event.target` will point to the element event is bound to. To get clicked element use `event.originalEvent.target`.